# Why does the accuracy of disparity decrease exponentially as distance increases?

Tags: image-processing, parallax, depth

The accuracy of estimated depth from disparity decreases exponentially as distance increases. This is the case for a depth estimator I created, but also other papers that I found on this subject. Why exactly is this the case? I understand that parallax decreases as  distance increases, but is this the only cause of the exponential increase in error?

None of the papers I found explicitly explains this as far as I understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show a reference where this is said ?

Comment: "High Accuracy Stereo Vision System for Far Distance Obstacle Detection", by Nedevschi. I read other too but can't find them now. If I find them later I will add

Comment: I found a couple of papers with some explanation. Just want to put it out there for other people looking. "Quantization error analysis in stereo vision" and "Method for measuring stereo camera depth accuracy based on stereoscopic vision"

Comment: Please point where this is said in the first paper.